# _TypeError (type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'UnmodifiableListView<String>')

Tags: flutter, dart

Anyone know why I would get this error when trying to setup a getter for an `UnmodifiableListView` in provider?

```
_TypeError (type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'UnmodifiableListView<String>')
```

Here is my code

```
List<String> _failures = [
    '>1.5 year',
    '3 months to 1.5 years',
    '2 weeks to 3 months',
    '2 days to 2 weeks',
    'Now',
  ];

UnmodifiableListView<String> get failures => _failures;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-collection/UnmodifiableListView/UnmodifiableListView.html).
Use this.

`UnmodifiableListView<String> get failures => UnmodifiableListView(_failures)`;